# dpkg-query lists multiple installed packages with the same name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

I list my installed packages by size using this command

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n\t${Version}\n' | sort -n
```

THis lists some packages twice with the same name but different sizes e.g.

```
177788  libwine 3.0-1ubuntu1
187570  libwine 3.0-1ubuntu1
232263  libgl1-mesa-dri 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
250581  libgl1-mesa-dri 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3
```

What does this mean?

Should I remove one of these duplicates? Which? How would I even select between them?

Comment: Try `'${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\t${Version}\n'`. Are they the same version? Note: see also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107039/95111) "Unfortunately on at least some systems, this list includes packages that have been removed but not purged."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu support a system called multiarch for packages which allows multiple packages with the same name but different architectures to be installed.  This is commonly used to install and use 32-bit software (usually the `i386` architecture) on 64-bit systems, but it can be used to install software for totally unrelated architectures as well (e.g., `arm64` on `amd64` hardware).

In this case, you probably have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of those packages installed.  Usually one installs Wine with both 32- and 64-bit modes, since many Windows programs, especially games, are still 32-bit.  Wine will require (or at least strongly recommend) OpenGL support, which is why you'll also see the Mesa libraries.

If you want to see this with `dpkg-query`, you can run this:

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}:${Architecture}\n\t${Version}\n'
```

which prints the architecture of the packages as well.